Uploading video files to S3 using expo and AWS Amplify
I have an application with which I would like to put videos in S3, and then return them to the user using pre-signed URLs. It is for a mobile application, where I am using expo-image-picker to get the image and the AWS Amplify Storage library to upload to S3. I have written the following code for it thus far:
const fetchImage = async (uri: string) => {
    const response = await fetch(uri);
    const blob = await response.blob();
    return blob;
  };

  const handleVideoUpload = async () => {
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
        mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Videos,
        allowsEditing: false,
        quality: 1
    })

    console.log(result)
    if(!result.canceled) {
        setSelectedVideo(result.assets[0].uri)
    }
  };

  const addVideoToFeed = async (videoUri: string, user_id: string, caption: string) => {
    try {
        // const userSub = (await fetchUserAttributes()).sub;
        const unique_id = uuid();
 
        // Get first 8 characters using slice
        const small_id = unique_id.slice(0, 8);
        const videoS3Path = `public/feedvideos/${small_id}`
        const videoData = await fetchImage(videoUri)
        const result = await uploadData({
            path: videoS3Path,
            data: videoData,
            contentType: 'video/mp4',
            options: {
                onProgress: ({ transferredBytes, totalBytes }) => {
                  if (totalBytes) {
                    console.log(
                      `Upload progress ${
                        Math.round((transferredBytes / totalBytes) * 100)
                      } %`
                    );
                  }
                },
              }
        }).result;

I can see the file in S3, but it is not a video file, and rather has no type. When I download it to my mac, the file simply has a "Document" type. In order to serve the content back to the user, I use the following code:
export async function generateVideoUrl(path: string) {

    try {
        const getUrlResult = await getUrl({
        path: path,
        options: {
            validateObjectExistence: true,
            expiresIn: 60000
        }
    })

    console.log("Signed url: ", getUrlResult.url.toString())
    if(getUrlResult.url.toString()) return getUrlResult.url.toString()
    else return "no_video_url"
} catch (err) {
    console.log("error in getting url: ", err)
    return "generate_video_url_error"
}
}

Wherein I then show the user the video in a video component as follows:
            <Video
              ref={index === activeIndex ? videoRef : null}
              source={{ uri: "newVidUrl!" }}
              style={styles.fullScreenVideo}
              resizeMode={ResizeMode.COVER}
              isLooping
              shouldPlay={index === activeIndex}
            />


The video, however, does not show up; I am not sure if this is an issue with how I upload the file or how I read it from the presigned URL.
Any help would be appreciated, thank you so much!
I have tried a variety of ways to encode the data before uploading, such as
    const videoData = await FileSystem.readAsStringAsync(videoUri, {
      encoding: FileSystem.EncodingType.Base64,
    });

    // Convert the video data to a Blob object
    const videoBlob = new Blob([videoData], { type: 'video/mp4' });

However, this would give the same issue.
